# How do you use two if_value_matches inside of Twilio studio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am new to Twilio and have a question regarding the use of the if_value_matches function. If you see below, I have a simple flow promoting the user to say yes or no and to respond to invalid commands. I have confirmed the Yes option and the invalid (referred to 'sorry' in the pic) function correctly. However, if I respond with NO it directs the flow down the invalid line of responses. Am I missing something simple here? Is there a better way to set up this flow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting the option in Uppercase e.g. NO,No,no

If it's text it for sure makes a difference